# Async method return System.Threading.Tasks.Task

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, asynchronous

I'm learning about asynchronous methods and I don't understand why asyn task method return

**System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1[System...**

Below is code:

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetAll(){
    try{
        var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(path,"database.db"));
            var value = await conn.Table<T>().ToListAsync();
            return value;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Info(TAG, "Error when selecting the registry. " + e.Message);
        }

        return null;
}
```

In this case the value is returned, but as System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1[System... and not as query return.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean - yes, it returns a task... that's how asynchronous methods work. They return you something that says, "I've started the work for you - the result will be in this task when it completes."

Comment: Sorry, let me be clearer. I believe when I run `conn.Table <T> (). ToListAsync () `return must be like (select * from datatable), for example, 2, but it is returning System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1 .. for who calls the` GetAll () `method.

Comment: Nope, I'm afraid that's no clearer at all... it still sounds like you should review what it means to call an asynchronous API. (If the method blocks until it can return the results directly, it can't be asynchronous, by definition...)

Comment: @EricSaboia your code *already* uses `ToListAsync()` which returns a Task. It *already* uses `await` to get its result. *Your* method is no different than `ToListAsync`. Both are asynchronous methods, that promise to return a value when an asynchronous method (somewhere inside ToListAsync) completes.

Comment: I believe that solve this problem, it occurred because the method to call GetAll() don't have i await before GetAll() method and was not async method. In this case, I need to put an answer on this question? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Any asynchronous task returns a Task object that allows to consult the status of the asynchronous request. If you want to access the result of the query you will have to consult the property *task.Result*, which contains the actual output of the asynchronous method.

Comment: That's a very bad idea because it will *block* until the asynchronous operation completes. The OP is already waiting for a result in the correct way - by using `await`